# Multidimensional Arrays enquiry PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-key

For example I have  array like below:

```
Array 
(
   [0] => Array
     (
        [a] => 1
        [b] => 0
        [c] => 1
        [d] => 1     
     )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [a] => 2
        [b] => 0
        [c] => 3
        [d] => 3 
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [a] => 5
        [b] => 1
        [c] => 3
        [d] => 2 
    )
```

)

Now I would like to receive only array with the largest [d] value.
So in this case:

```
Array (
        [a] => 2
        [b] => 0
        [c] => 3
        [d] => 3
    )
```

What is the easiest and the most optimal way to do it?
Thank You!

Comment: Are you try anything? Keys are ok? `a b d d` should be rather `a b c d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$res=array();
    foreach ($array as $temp)
    {
        foreach ($temp as $k=>$value)
        {
            if(!isset($res[$k]))
            {
                $res[$k]=$value;
            }
            else
            {
                $res[$k]=max($value,$res[$k]);
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($res);
```

> output Array ( [a] => 5 [b] => 1 [c] => 3 [d] => 3 )

**Update Answer**

```
$res=array();
    $max=0;
    foreach ($array as $temp)
    {
        if($max<$temp['d'])
        {
             $max=$temp['d'];
            $res=$temp;
        }
    }
    print_r($res);
```

> output Array ( [a] => 2 [b] => 0 [c] => 3 [d] => 3 )

Comment: That's not what I meant.

What if array looks like:
'$array = Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        "a" => "1",
        "b" => "0",
        "c" => "1",
        "d" => "1"
     ),
    1 => Array
    (
        "a" => "1",
        "b" => "5",
        "c" => "1",
        "d" => "2"
    ),
    4 => Array
    (
        "a" => "1",
        "b" => "0",
        "c" => "1",
        "d" => "3"
    )
);'

Output is: Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 5 [c] => 1 [d] => 3 )

But I would like to receive :  Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 0 [c] => 1 [d] => 3 )

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = Array 
(
   [0] => Array
     (
        [a] => 1
        [b] => 0
        [c] => 1
        [d] => 1     
     )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [a] => 2
        [b] => 0
        [c] => 3
        [d] => 3 
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [a] => 5
        [b] => 1
        [c] => 3
        [d] => 2 
    ));

    uasort ( $array, function ($a, $b) {
            return $a['d'] > $b['d'];
        }
    );

$valueYouAreSearchingFor = $array[0];
```

I used uasort to sort the array using an anonymous function. I'd have to test if it's faster than a ForEach loop, but it deffinitely is more fun (at least if you ask me :) )

If you don't want to change the original array, make a copy and sort the copy.

PS: Google is your friend...

Comment: I would take this concise approach over the accepted answer any day, regardless of any marginal performance gains.

Answer (score 0):

```
$subArray1 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 0, 'c' => 1, 'd' => 1);
$subArray2 = array('a' => 2, 'b' => 0, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 3);
$subArray3 = array('a' => 5, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 2);
$data = array($subArray1, $subArray2, $subArray3);

$resultArray = array();
/*
Turn off 'notification' level errors or add 'isset' checks
*/
foreach($data as $subArray)
{
    foreach($subArray as $key => $value)
    {
        $resultArray[$key] = max($resultArray[$key], $value);
    }
}
var_dump($resultArray);
```

Comment: Your result is Array ( [a] => 5 [b] => 1 [c] => 3 [d] => 3 ),
not  Array ( [a] => 2 [b] => 0 [c] => 3 [d] => 3 ),